# Why is my text file always empty?

Tags: java, file, io

I have created a game that saves your high score in a text file called highscores.txt. When I open the game, the correct high score is displayed. But when I open the text file, it is always empty. Why is this? Here is my code for writing and reading the text file.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("highscores.txt");
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);

highScore = din.readInt();
highSScore.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
din.close();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("highscores.txt");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

dos.writeInt(highScore);
dos.close();
```

Comment: Because you're opening a file containing non-text in a text editor?

Comment: @immibis That might be good as an answer.

Comment: Good catch. OP, if you're on a Unix system, try "xxd highscores.txt", see if you get text or binary.

Comment: What is `highSScore`. You don't define it in the code. Please provide a full minimal example...

Comment: try `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("highscores.txt"));` and `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("highscores.txt"));`? I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: highSScore is a JLabel I use  to display the high score on the screen. Edward I tried what you said and I got " ð" when the high score was 240.  immibis, can you please tell me why my file has non text.

Comment: Gosu I tried what you said and it did not work, but thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to write to file you can also use `FileWriter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataOutputStream.writeInt` does not write an integer as text; it writes a "raw" or "binary" integer consisting of 4 bytes. If you try to interpret them as text (such as by viewing them in a text editor), you get garbage, because they're not text.

For example, if your score is 100, `writeInt` will write a 0 byte, a 0 byte, a 0 byte, and a 100 byte (in that order). 0 is an invalid character (when interpreted as text) and 100 happens to be the letter "d".

If you want to write a text file, you could use `Scanner` for parsing (reading) and `PrintWriter` for writing - something like this:

```
// for reading
FileReader fin = new FileReader("highscores.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fin);

highScore = din.nextInt();
highScore.setText("High Score: " + highScore);
sc.close();

// for writing
FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("highscores.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
pw.println(highScore);
pw.close();
```

(of course, there are many other ways you could do this)